# caching not working in datalayer

Tags: asp.net, caching

When using HttpContext.Current.Cache in my data layer, nothing is cached. I am using this code:

```
  public List<Review> GetReviews()
 {           
            List<Review> reviews = new List<Review>();
            string cacheKey = "my_reviews";

            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
                reviews = (List<Review>)HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
            else
            {
                reviews = (List<Review>)Review.Find(review => review.NodeId == nodeId && review.IsDeleted == false);
                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, reviews, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
           return reviews;
}
```

When I call the method again, nothing is cached.

If I use the exact same code in my UI-layer, everything is working as expected, and the reviews are cached.

Why can't I cache the reviews in the data layer?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Does your data layer have a reference to System.Web? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see what the actual control flow looks like?

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes, I reference system.web in my data layer, and I also tried stepping through my code. If I do the caching in the UI-layer, the reviews are cached the next time I refresh the page. But it does not cache in the data layer. I also tried passing the HttpContext from the UI-layer to the data layer, but that did not work either

Comment: Hi, another part of the code was removing the item from the cache. So the caching works, the coder doesn't ;-)